# Frama-C 23 and Coq

Tags: macos, coq, frama-c, why3

After installing Frama-C (23), Why3, and Coq on macOS I ran the command

```
rm -f ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config detect
```

The following message was shown

```
Found prover Coq version 8.10.2, but no Why3 libraries were compiled for it
```

- Does this mean I cannot use coq with Frama-C?
- How do I instruct opam to compile the above mentioned Why3 libraries?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it might be more a Why3 question than a Frama-C question. Anyway, you have to install the Opam package `why3-coq` so that you have Why3 libraries compiled for Coq (and then re-execute `why3 config detect`).

Comment: I had completely forgotten about `why3-coq`. Thanks a lot. Configuration of provers now includes `coq`.